# Perform action upon chassis intrustion detection

Tags: linux, security, gnu, bios

Given:

- a server running GNU/Linux, and
- a chassis intrusion detection switch on that server, and
- a BIOS (or UEFI) in that server, that tracks the intrusion detection status such that the status can be read via `freeipmi` or similar,

how can that server best be made to perform some action (e.g. send an email, or simply shutdown) if the server's chassis is opened?

User [forest](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/106285/forest) on security.stackexchange suggested polling "[`/dev/nvram` once every 0.5 seconds or so [to] parse it for whatever value stores the chassis intrusion count](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/119269)." (License: [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).) This seems inefficient. Surely there is a better way?

Comment: check this out: https://firmware.intel.com/blog/accessing-uefi-variables-linux

Comment: @ron, not your fault (unless you're Intel's webmaster), but that URL has a fishy HTTPS implementation. It serves an invalid certificate, and scores low on SSLLabs: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=firmware.intel.com . Any chance you could post an answer summarising what that page provides that might be useful in answering my question above?

Comment: the link has no problem for me and I am behind a corp. proxy and firewall at the moment.  I will post the contents of the link below as an answer.

Comment: also look into `biosdecode` and `dmidecode`.  And here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133899/chassis-intrusion-api

Answer (score 1):

below is quoted from: firmware.intel.com/blog/accessing-uefi-variables-linux

> Posted by mfleming on 01/3/2014
>
> This article gives a summary of the two methods Linux provides for accessing UEFI runtime variables, along with the tradeoffs and a
>   little bit of history.
>
> ```
> The Legacy efivars Interface
> ```
>
> The original interface, written by Matt Domsch, for interacting with UEFI variables is exported via the all-purpose Linux kernel sysfs
>   filesystem. This interface was created in the days of EFI, before
>   UEFI, for use with Itanium machines and so comes with a certain amount
>   of historical baggage.
>
> The legacy efivars interface is exported via the path "firmware/efi/vars/" relative to the mount point of sysfs. Assuming
>   that sysfs is mounted at /sys, the directory containing the efivars
>   files will be,
>
> ```
>     /sys/firmware/efi/vars/
> ```
>
> Apart from the special files `new_var` and `del_var`, each entry in the above mount point is itself a directory - one directory for
>   every UEFI variable that is accessible at runtime,
>
> ```
>     Boot0000-12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-123456789abc/
>     Boot0001-12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-123456789abc/
>     BootCurrent-12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-123456789abc/
>     BootOrder-12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-123456789abc/
>     BootSetup-12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-123456789abc/
>     del_var
>     Lang-12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-123456789abc/
>     LangCodes-12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-123456789abc/
>     new_var
>     Setup-12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-123456789abc/
> ```
>
> The directory name for a UEFI variable is composed of the variable name and the variable's Globally Unique Identifier (GUID). This
>   example:
>
> ```
>     Boot0000-12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-123456789abc/
> ```
>
> could be the directory for the first UEFI Boot Variable. Within each directory the following files can be found,
>
> ```
>     attributes
>     data
>     guid
>     raw_var
>     size
> ```
>
> The contents of most of these files are human readable, and correspond to the UEFI variable parameters of the same name. The
>   exception being the 'raw_var' file, which contains binary data. For
>   instance, the 'attributes' file for the above Boot entry would contain
>   something like the following ASCII strings,
>
> ```
>     EFI_VARIABLE_NON_VOLATILE
>     EFI_VARIABLE_BOOTSERVICE_ACCESS
>     EFI_VARIABLE_RUNTIME_ACCESS
> ```
>
> to indicate that the variable is non-volatile, and accessible both before and after calling the UEFI Boot Service, ExitBootServices().
>   It's not possible to write to these human readable files - their only
>   purpose is to provide users with details of the variable.
>
> `raw_var` allows the UEFI variable binary data structure used within the kernel to be read/written from user space, and is a core
>   piece of the legacy interface. All modifications to existing variables
>   are performed via this file by passing a 'struct efi_variable' object,
>
> ```
> struct efi_variable {
>
>     efi_char16_t VariableName[1024/sizeof(efi_char16_t)];
>     efi_guid_t VendorGuid;
>     unsigned long DataSize;
>     __u8 Data[1024];
>     efi_status_t Status;
>     __u32 Attributes;
>
> } __attribute__((packed));
> ```
>
> The special files 'new_var' and 'del_var' in the top directory are used, as the names imply, for creating and deleting UEFI variables.
>   These files do not use human-readable text. Instead, 'struct
>   efi_variable' objects are passed back and forth between the kernel and
>   user space, to either create new, or delete existing UEFI variables.
>
> The primary reason for keeping the efivars interface around in the Linux kernel is that there are still tools that will only use this
>   interface: the efibootmgr tool, which is available on all Linux
>   distributions to
>   control the boot order on UEFI systems, still uses this legacy interface.
>
> However, there are some limitations of the legacy efivars interface which, overtime, have started to become a major headache.
>
> The most apparent shortcoming is that there is an upper limit on the size of UEFI variable data that can be read/written. Because of
>   the way that the kernel data structures were designed, it is not
>   possible to read or write more than 1024 bytes of variable data, and
>   for some use cases, that limit is a problem.
>
> Furthermore, the efivars interface intrinsically requires tools to manipulate UEFI variables because the interface only deals with
>   reading and writing copies of the non-trivial 'struct efi_variable'
>   data structure for a UEFI variable via the 'new_var', 'del_var' and
>   'raw_var' special files. It is not possible to delete a UEFI variable
>   without building a 'struct efi_variable' object and writing it to the
>   'del_var' file.
>
> ### The efivarfs file system
>
> To sidestep the limitations of the legacy efivar interface a brand new Linux file system was created by Matthew Garrett and Jeremy Kerr.
>   This new file system was named "efivarfs" and was part of the Linux
>   kernel v3.10 release.
>
> Like all other Linux file systems, efivarfs must be mounted somewhere to access its files, which can be done by issuing the
>   following command,
>
> ```
>     mount -t efivarfs none /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
> ```
>
> Instead of directories, efivarfs contains files whose names are built from the UEFI variables' name and GUID,
>
> ```
>     Boot0000-12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-123456789abc
>     Boot0001-12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-123456789abc
>     BootCurrent-12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-123456789abc
>     BootOrder-12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-123456789abc
>     BootSetup-12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-123456789abc
> ```
>
> Even though each of the files contains binary data (like the `new_var`, `del_var` of the legacy interface), the data structure for
>   efivarfs is much simpler, consisting only of 4 bytes for the UEFI
>   variable attributes bitmask, and the rest is the UEFI variable data,
>   e.g.
>
> ```
> struct new_efi_variable
> {
>
>    u32 attributes;
>    u8 data[0];
>
> };
> ```
>
> All other pieces of information, such as the variable name, GUID and size are inferred from the filename being read/written. This makes
>   it trivial to create, or delete a UEFI variable by creating or
>   deleting files.
>
> For example, the following shell command creates a new variable,
>
> ```
>     printf "\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00" > myvar-12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc
> ```
>
> named `myvar` with the GUID `12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc`, and the
>   `EFI_VARIABLE_NON_VOLATILE`, `EFI_VARIABLE_BOOTSERVICE_ACCESS` and
>   `EFI_VARIABLE_RUNTIME_ACCESS` bits set in the attribute bitmask,
>   followed by 1 byte of data (the final `\x00`).
>
> The size of a variable, plus the 4 bytes of attribute data, can be found by using any of the usual methods for getting the size of a
>   file. For example, running the following shell command,
>
> ```
>     du -b myvar-12345678-1234-1234-1234-12345678abc
> ```
>
> will print '5' - that's 4 bytes for the variable attribute bitmask, plus one byte of data.
>
> To delete the variable, simply remove it from the efivarfs file system,
>
> ```
>     rm myvar-12345678-1234-1234-1234-12345678abc
> ```
>
> Clearly, this is a much more intuitive interface for accessing UEFI variables from the command line and from shell scripts. Most
>   importantly, there's no limit on the amount of data that can be
>   read/written for a UEFI variable, unlike with the legacy interface.
>
> Of course, even though the data structure used by efivarfs is much simpler than the legacy interface, it is still read/written as binary
>   data and requires more mental processing than the human readable files
>   provided by the legacy interface.
>
> In this article we have briefly discussed the two solutions that Linux provides for accessing UEFI variables at runtime. While the new
>   efivarfs file system provides a useful interface for accessing UEFI
>   variables from shell scripts (and even from the command line), the
>   legacy interface is still used by some tools, and in some situations
>   the human readable files can be much more useful than the binary only
>   interface of efivarfs.
>
> *Matt Fleming is a software engineer at Intel's Open Source Technology Center and the Linux kernel (U)EFI maintainer.*